# SCCM 2012: Can I deploy Config Manager Server as Hyper-V virtual machine?

Tags: hyper-v, sccm, sccm-2012

I have planned to install SCCM 2012 on Windows server 2012 virtual machine.  Let me know the system requirements of Visualization?  This should be support up to 50 users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Answer (score 3):

The SCCM system requirements and configurations are tuned to support very large enterprises. We're running SCCM for 300 devices/users with 2 vCpu's and 8GB RAM.

Remember, these are unofficial statements and you'll have no guarantee that it works in *your* environment. Our SCCM was painfully slow until we upped it from 6 to 8GB RAM, but that doesn't mean it's the answer for you.

Just make sure that you limit how much RAM the SCCM SQL server is allowed to eat up if you're going to run SQL on the same virtual server.